# How to read react-dom.development errors from the console log

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-dom

Sometimes I get errors on the console that are traceable i.e PageName/:LineNumber

but I get errors like this

`react-dom.development.js?f731:67`.

What are these errors and where can I know how to debug them?